# How to make a connection string in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I added an Entity to my Windows Application and this is my whole code.

```
Imports MSWord.FirstBSEntities

Private db As FirstBSEntities

Private Sub btnOpen_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOpen.Click
    AxEDOffice1.OpenFileDialog()
    Dim Count As Integer = AxEDOffice1.WordGetPageCount
    Dim Id As Integer = (From a In db.FirstBS Select a.BSId).FirstOrDefault()
    Label1.Text = Id * Count
End Sub
```

**App.Config**

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FirstBSEntities" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
           connectionString="Data Source=SQL\SQL2008;Initial Catalog=FirstBS; Integrated Security=true" />
    <!--<add name="FirstBSEntities" connectionString="Data Source=SQL\SQL2008;Initial Catalog=FirstBSEntities;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <add name="FirstBSEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SQL\SQL2008;initial catalog=FirstBS;user id=sa;password=P@ssw0rd;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

I am new in making of connection string and I got this error in my linq

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: You did not declare FirstBSEntities with the `New` keyword.

Comment: @OneFineDay I also try `Private db = New FirstBSEntities`

Comment: What object is the error referring to?

Comment: This has got nothing to do with the connection string.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it?rq=1

Comment: @jmcilhinney my tables has values..

Comment: Noone said it didn't. Stop wasting time here and go and debug your code.  When the exception is thrown, it will indicate which line it occurred on and you can then test each reference on that line to see which one is null.

Comment: `I got this error in my linq`